# TypeError:hash must be unicode or bytes,not int

Tags: html, mysql, sql, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am working Flash in Visual Studio Code.I have Windows 10 Home. And I am trying to do a website.I have register page and login page.Register page is working but when I try to login with my username and password,I take the TypeError. So I check the my code but I can't find the anything about the errror.

There is my code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,flash,redirect,url_for,session,logging,request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from wtforms import Form,StringField,TextAreaField,PasswordField,validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField("Name Surname",validators=[validators.Length(min=4,max=25)])
    username = StringField("Username",validators=[validators.Length(min=5,max=35)])
    email = StringField("Email Adress",validators=[validators.Email(message = "Please enter a valid email.")])
    password = PasswordField("Password:",validators=[
        validators.DataRequired(message = "Please enter an email."),
        validators.EqualTo(fieldname="confirm",message = "Your password doesn't match")
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField("Verify Password")

class LoginForm(Form):
    username =StringField("Username")
    password =PasswordField("Password")



app = Flask(__name__) #Flask objesi oluşturuyoruz.
app.secret_key= "ybblog"

app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] =""
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] ="ybblog"
app.config["MYSQL_CURSORCLASS"] = "DictCursor"

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")


@app.route("/register",methods =["GET","POST"])    
def register():
    form =RegisterForm(request.form)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        name = form.name.data 
        username = form.username.data
        email = form.email.data 
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(form.password.data)
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        
        query = "Insert into users(name,email,username,password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        
        cursor.execute(query,(name,email,username,password))
        mysql.connection.commit()

        cursor.close()
        
        flash("Login is succesful.","success")

        return redirect(url_for("index"))
    else:
        return render_template("register.html",form = form)

    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    
    if request.method == "POST" :
        username = form.username.data
        password_entered = form.password.data

        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()

        query = "Select * From users where username = %s"
        result = cursor.execute(query,(username,))

        if result > 0:
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            real_password = data["password"]
            if sha256_crypt.verify(password_entered,real_password):
                flash("Login is succesful.","success")
                return redirect(url_for("index"))
            else:
                flash("Wrong password.","danger")
                return redirect(url_for("login"))    

        else:
            flash("There is no such user.","danger")
            return redirect(url_for("login"))


    return render_template("login.html",form=form)    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Also I have about.html,index.html,layout.html,login.html and register.html html pages.But When I try to register it html pages are running.So I think the problem is my login function.

There is the error :

```
TypeError:
TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes,not int


File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Deneme2\blog3.py", line 85, in login
if sha256_crypt.verify(password_entered,real_password):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\passlib\utils\handlers.py", line 788, in verify
self = cls.from_string(hash, **context)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\passlib\handlers\sha2_crypt.py", line 304, in from_string
hash = to_unicode(hash, "ascii", "hash")
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\passlib\utils\__init__.py", line 764, in to_unicode
raise ExpectedStringError(source, param)
TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not int
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: please show  us the complete error message as text, and look for tutotrials that help you debug your code, as it stands

Comment: I added the error how is it looks like @nbk

Comment: we need the concrete error mesage with all text please

Comment: I added the full error @nbk

Comment: for sime reason i pthon thinks data["password"] is an int, but iot should be a byte array, see what you get and also chekc the database, somewhere you lost some bytes

Comment: I am following a Python video series and I watched abput this video more than 5 time. Please can you help me? I've been dealing with this for a long time and couldn't find anything @nbk

Comment: that i can't do, you have to chekc all variables involved and see what type they are. may a conversion helps. i can't understand where the int comes from. for that i would need html database and all. go step by step and you will find the culprit